# Как убрать сдвиг контента мобильным меню на Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать сдвиг контента мобильного меню на Bootstrap 4?

На мобильном, при клике на гамбургер - открывается меню, и это меню сдвигает контент вниз. А планируется сделать, чтобы пункты меню были поверх контента

- [Как происходит сейчас](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/212906/)
- [Как планируется реализация](https://marvelapp.com/5g9g1a5/screen/47555742)

Навигация стандартная бутсрапа

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

Comment: Уточните, что именно за сдвиг?

Comment: Добавил дополнения в сам вопрос

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Какой сдвиг? Уточните вопрос, красная стрелка ни о чем не говорит.

Answer (score 0):

Добавте класс `fixed-top`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
```

Answer (score 0):

У Bootstrap имеется класс "position-absolute", но чисто этим классом вы не обойдётесь, так как стили не расcчитаны на position: absolute;
Поэтому вообще не нужно добавлять класс "position-absolute", а вместо этого дописать стили, которые я привёл ниже.
За идеальную точность стилей отвечать не могу, так как применял эти стили перейдя по первой ссылке, которую вы дали на ".navbar-collapse", у вас просто код может отличаться, ведь вы предоставили лишь одну строчку html)).

```css
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light position-absolute">
```